# How to differentiate to individual UICollectionViewCell processing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How to differentiate to individual `UICollectionViewCell` processing. I handle it according to `indexPath` row  will be a problem.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question a bit for us.

Comment: I have already done.However,I can't change the content of the custom item, for example, I would like to select an item and then change his text color, the other parts of the item will change as well.

Answer (score 0):

UICollection view has a delegate method similar to tableView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.imagesGallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    [cell addSubview:image];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have already done.However,I can't change the content of the custom item, for example, I would like to select an item and then change his text color, the other parts of the item will change as well.

Comment: I see, in this case, you would likely determine a state of a selected item in your data source, and call reload on the collectionView to display the updated cells